# ZipException: duplicate entry exception

Tags: java, android, firebase, gradle, firebaseui

I'm making Android chat bot app with Firebase and API.AI.
After adding firebase UI lib to project, I got **java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry** runtime exception.After that, I've added javaMaxHeapSize = "4g" but could not find a solution for this.Tried with different FirebaseUI versions, but none of them worked.

There are other similar questions, but each is generic with different build.grade.

Here is message:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/internal/zzf.class
```

Gradle files:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 25
  buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.bot.chatbot.chatbot"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled = true
  }
  dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize = "4g"
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
  })

  //Google
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
  compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

  //AI
  compile 'ai.api:sdk:2.0.7@aar'
  compile 'ai.api:libai:1.4.8'
  compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
  compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'

  //Firebase
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.1'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1'
  compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.3'
  compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.3.0'


  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Second one :

```
 buildscript {
      repositories {
        jcenter()
      }
      dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

      }
    }

    allprojects {
      repositories {
        jcenter()
      }
    }

task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: A ZIP file can contains a file location only one time. Some part of the tasks add the entry two times.

Comment: The [FirebaseUI docs](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#dependencies) explain the requirements for version compatibility.  For Firebase libs 10.2.1, use `firebase-ui:1.2.0`.  And delete the line for `firebase-ui-database`. Because you are including all of FirebaseUI with `firebase-ui:1.2.0`, it's not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are mixing the old dependencies with new ones. So in order to solve your problem, delete the following line of code from your build.gradle file.

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.3.0'
```

This line of code is no needed and that's why you get `duplicate entry exception`. See the version compatibility for the `FirebaseUI` i suggest you see the offical [documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#dependencies).